# Why stops useEffect Hook?

Tags: react-native, hook, use-effect

In my application I want to display a timer which can be started and stopped by the user. For this I created a timer state: `const [timer, setTimer] = useState({"minutes" : 0, "seconds" : 0})`and use a useEffect hook to increment the values periodically.

If I'm using:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const displayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    if(timer.seconds < 59) {
      setTimer({"minutes": timer.minutes, "seconds" : timer.seconds + 1})
    }
    else {
      setTimer({"minutes": timer.minutes + 1, "seconds" : 0})
    }
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(displayTimer);
});
```

everything works fine. The timer runs until infinity. But after adding the if statement, to stop the timer, nothing happens anymore. I can't start the timer.

Heres the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const displayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    if(active) {
      if(timer.seconds < 59) {
        setTimer({"minutes": timer.minutes, "seconds" : timer.seconds + 1})
      }
      else {
        setTimer({"minutes": timer.minutes + 1, "seconds" : 0})
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(displayTimer);
});
```

The active var is a useState hook which is toggled by a button.
With `console.log` I found out, the useEffect isn't called anymore after adding the if. But why? Can anyone help me to get my timer working?

Answer (score 1):

The effect function closes over the `active` variable's initial state, so it will always be true.

All dependencies need to be included in the dependencies array of the effect, like
`useEffect(() => {}, [active])`

Comment: After adding the dependency the effect is just called once after changing the value but not periodically every second

Comment: Oh you were actually relying on running the effect on every render. That's no good because any prop changes would also inc the timer. You want something like this https://github.com/craig1123/react-recipes/blob/master/src/useInterval.js

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me and solved the problem 